# iOS Splash Screen Stretched

Tags: ios, resolution, splash-screen

Setting up a splash screen for my app (320x480, 640x960, etc), yet it seems to be stretched in the y-axis. I then thought it might be a case of it having the UIStatusBar so I re-created the Splash Screens at a smaller resolution (320x460, 640x920, etc) yet I'm still experiencing the same issue.

Thoughts?

Comment: Have you named the files correctly..? Have you also added a separate image for iPhone 5. Please share the file names used for iPhone, iPhone Retina & iPhone 5. Screenshots of the Phone will also be handy..

Comment: on which device/simulator are you testing? iPhone5 would be 640x1136 ... http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

Comment: I have named them correctly- Default.png, Default@2x.png, Default-568h@2x.png. And the sizes are correct as well. I am on the iPhone 4 simulator.